# How to group a set of row from a table by every possible combination of 3 other tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping, cross-join

Here are the table structures

```
Table A (id, name)
Table B (id, A-id)
Table C (id, quantity, B-id, D-id)
Table D (id, E-id, F-id)
Table E (id, name)
Table F (id, name)
```

I want to get the result like this

```
A.name | E.name | F.name | SUM(C.quantity) 
-------------------------------------------
foo    | aaa    | zzz    | 50
-------------------------------------------
foo    | aaa    | xxx    | 0
-------------------------------------------
foo    | bbb    | www    | 10
-------------------------------------------
bar    | aaa    | zzz    | 12
-------------------------------------------
bar    | aaa    | xxx    | 1
-------------------------------------------
bar    | bbb    | www    | 30
-------------------------------------------
```

I have to show all entries in `A`, `E`, and `F` even though there is no entry related to them in C.

So basically I have to group all data in `C` by every possible combination of `A`, `E`, and `F` and show `0` if there is no data available in `C`.

How do I do that?

Comment: You've got a problem in that there is no correlation between A, E and F without going through D and C. And if there is no data available in C, how can you link them together? Or do you need to do a CROSS JOIN to get every possible combination of A, E and F? This would result in a huge amount of data, even if there were only 10 values in each of A, E and F you'd have 1,000 rows.

Comment: yea, I want to get every possible combination of A, E, and F. It's for reporting so it doesn't really matter if it is slow.

Comment: It's still contradictory. If `a`, `e` and `f` are unrelated,  there is a conflict when you want to join `c`. How to resolve that?

Comment: Please update your question to reflect your actual requirements (that you *want* all combinations of a, e and f).

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of [**`CROSS JOIN`**, **`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) and [**`COALESCE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

If you want a `CROSS JOIN`, which is pretty unusual and may produce **a lot** of rows, it could look like this.
Even more aggressive after **update**: `b` and `d` are also optional now.

```
SELECT a.name AS a_name, e.name AS e_name, f.name AS f_name
      ,COALESCE(sum(c.quantity), 0) As sum_quantity
FROM   a
CROSS  JOIN e
CROSS  JOIN f
LEFT   JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
LEFT   JOIN d ON d.e_id = e.id
             AND d.f_id = f.id
LEFT   JOIN c ON c.b_id = b.id
             AND c.d_id = d.id
GROUP  BY 1,2,3;
```

For lack of specification I join `c` only if both `b_id` **and** `d_id` have a match.

#### Additional Q in comment

> In your last answer you put a parenthesis after cross join, what does
> that do?

I quote [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):

> Use parentheses if necessary to determine the order of nesting. In
> the absence of parentheses, JOINs nest left-to-right. In any case JOIN
> binds more tightly than the commas separating FROM items.

Comment: This won't include info from E and F when there is no matching record in C, which was one of the (impossible) requirements.

Comment: Huh... I never knew `GROUP BY` worked on `SELECT` index. Learn something new every day!

Comment: @MarkOrmston: You can use positional parameters in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` - referring to the position in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Hmm, I think I have to cross join both E and F with B. Because if there is no entry in D, I get nothing in the result. But still I don't know how, this is so confusing haha. So cross join E and F with B and then join E and F with D? The data in D will be redundant then.

Comment: In your last answer you put a parenthesis after cross join, what does that do?

Comment: @William:  You can instruct Postgres handle a group of joins together. Overrule the default operator precedence. You also create an optimization barrier, keeping Postgres to reorder joins as it sees fit. With plain joins this is hardly ever useful. I use them sometimes when I know from experience it's best to `JOIN` certain tables before joining to the rest. With `LEFT JOIN` / `CROSS JOIN` it may be, though. My final solution doesn't need it. I added a bit to my answer.